# How to split a column into two in ReportLab

Tags: python, python-3.x, reportlab

I need to split a column in a table into two. So far I've tried to do it by embedding the table as follows, but I'm sure there's a simpler way to do it. Thanks in advance for your help!

My table:

[image: Table photo]

```
table_data = [
    [
        Paragraph("Konto", data_paragraph_style),
        Paragraph("Nr Dowodu", data_paragraph_style),
    ],
    [
        Table(
            data=[
                [
                    Paragraph(
                        "Winien",
                        data_paragraph_style,
                    ),
                    Paragraph(
                        "Ma",
                        data_paragraph_style,
                    ),
                ],
                [
                    Paragraph(
                        "",
                        data_paragraph_style,
                    ),
                    Paragraph(
                        "",
                        data_paragraph_style,
                    ),
                ],
            ],
            colWidths=[50, 50],
            style=[
                ("GRID", (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.5, colors.black),
                ("ALIGN", (0, 0), (-1, -1), "CENTER"),
                ("VALIGN", (0, 0), (-1, -1), "MIDDLE"),
                ("FONTNAME", (0, 0), (-1, -1), "Arial"),
                ("FONTSIZE", (0, 0), (-1, -1), 10),
                ("BOTTOMPADDING", (0, 0), (-1, -1), 12),
                ("TEXTCOLOR", (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.whitesmoke),
            ],
        ),
    ],
]
```

I want the table to look as follows, or very similar:

[image]